# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line of the JSON data

Tags: jquery, json

i'm almost done with a tutorial for making comments with ajax but i'm getting this error and i can't find an answer to it ! Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < ... SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line of the JSON data

**comment_insert.php**
((The file in which the callback should be sent to))

```
if(class_exists('Comments') && class_exists('Subscribers'))
        {
            $userInfo= Subscribers::getSubscriber($userId);

            if($userInfo == null)
            {
            $std->error = true;
            }
            $commentInfo= Comments::insert($comment , $userId);

            if ($commentInfo == null)
            {
            $std->error = true;
            }

            $std->user = $userInfo;
            $std->comment = $commentInfo;       
        }

        echo json_encode($std);
```

**comment_insert.js**

```
$.post("comment_insert.php",
            {
                task: "comment_insert",
                userId: _userId,
                comment: _comment
            }

        )
        .success(function(data)
            {
                //task: insert html into the ul/li

                comment_insert($.parseJSON(data));
                console.log("ResponseText: " + data);
            });
```

Comment: What does the json returned look like?

Comment: Probably a good idea to dump the JSON you get from PHP to see what's going on

Comment: I personally think that your PHP is spitting out an error, hence the `"Unexpected <..."`

Comment: @scrowler ->>Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'comment_id' of undefined comment_insert.js

Comment: @Darren debugger could't tell me where it's ! just anonymous !

Comment: Open the console, go to the Network tab, run the code so it contacts your `comment_insert.php` page, go the Response part of the request, and copy and paste that into your question.

Comment: Also, add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your php script to turn error reporting on.

Comment: @Jared .. Response is {"user":null,"comment":null,"error":true}

Comment: Whenever I've seen this error in the past, it's because the server was throwing an uncaught error and returning HTML instead of JSON (so the first character is `<`, which JSON.parse can't handle).